# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS , Laptop to tablet on dell inspiron 13 7000 2in1

Tags: dell, tablet, 18.04

I have a Dell inspiron 13 7000 which doubles up as a tablet. I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Now when i flip my screen to tablet mode, it gives me the keyboard on the desktop but as soon as i touch the browser and open it, the keyboard is gone , how can i make this work as a Tablet ?

Answer (score 2):

Put the keyboard button in the top bar. Gnome extension is available [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1061/on-screen-keyboard-button/).